# Local toast notification in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, toast

I want to develop an app for Windows Phone which contains a “Notification”.

My idea:

At 01:00 PM, a toast notification shows, like this:

[image: AppTest: Now, it's 01:00 pm]

And every day at 1 pm the toast notification is shown.

Please guide me how to do this in VB Net.

I tried “Alarm”, but it did not work for me:

```
Dim dg As New Alarm
With dg
.Content = ""
.Title = ""
.BeginTime = Date.Now.AddSeconds(10)
End With
ScheduledActionService.Add(dg)
```

I think it’s `Background agent , ShellToast` but how should I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to show is Toast Notification. I understand that it works only when you app runs in background and not as as a foreground app.

You need to use object of *ShellToast* class

```
    ShellToast toast = newShellToast();
    toast.Content = "This is a local toast";
    toast.Title = "MYAPP";
    toast.Show();
```

See this for more info  on toast notification
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/shell-notifications-windows

Comment: Take a look at this   [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_simple_Background_Agent_in_Windows_Phone)

Answer (score 0):

we cant show toast notification as a localnotification. we need to use Alarm notification for it.